# How can i Amplify mp3 Sound in Android programmatically

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3

I am using some mp3 files in my android aap. Its volume is very low. How can i amplify its sound by 3 times programmatically.

Comment: Can you do this with Equalizer? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to boost the mp3 sound programmatically then it will cost a lot cpu usage, (which for a low end device is a serious matter) and also you have some pre-loaded mp3 to play so my suggestion is to pre-increase the sound volume of those mp3s (using some sound editing software like [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)) and then use those in your app.

Comment: actually the mp3 files are very small in size, less than 20kb each. and  we have done same thing in apple (IOS) it workes fine. but i dont know how to do it in android

Comment: Any programmatic solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SoundPool, the play function includes a volume parameter. Does that help? You should boost the sound in the file itself though as @orchidrudra suggests as this will only let you make it quieter.

Comment: Any programmatic solution to this problem either using php or android?